# Telnet behaviour on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, telnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force telnet client into character mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273261/force-telnet-client-into-character-mode)

I'm working on writing a MUD-like game (in Python, if that matters).  I've noticed that the Windows telnet client and Ubuntu's telnet client behave slightly differently when connecting to the server.

In Ubuntu, I type something, but the server doesn't recieve anything until I press enter.  With Windows, every keystroke is sent to the server.

I want every client that connects to exhibit the behaviour I get from Ubuntu.  I've tried implementing a buffer server-side, but I keep on running into issues (the latest being how I should handle backspace).

Is there any special command I can send to set the 'mode' of the telnet client?  Or any recommended reading to better understand what's going on here?

UPDATE:  It looks like all I have to do is run the following line as soon as a person connects.

```
socket.send( chr(255)+chr(251)+chr(34) )  #IAC WILL LINEMODE
```

However, this doesn't seem to have any effect.  Anybody have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE 2:  Found the problem.  My server was sending everything it received from a user to every other user.  This includes the acknowledgement that it gets from the client after I set the mode -- which produced some really screwy results.