# Not able to capture "\t" tab from telnet client

Tags: c, input, tabs, telnet

Last question I asked can be found in below link related to the same problem,

[How to implement tab completion on the telnet client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467444/how-to-implement-tab-completion-on-the-telnet-client-side)

but now as I started implementing taking the inputs from the answers I got, I am facing some more issues.
Let me put my code snippet

```
send(tClntSockFd, "377/375/042/377/373/001", 6, 0));    
while(lineIndex < CMD_MAX_LEN)    {    
/* Receive from the client */        
  if (RHU_FAILURE == (numbytes = recv(tClntSockFd,usrCommand, CMD_MAX_LEN, 0))) {
    RHU_LOG1(RHU_CM_CLI, RHU_LOG_ERROR, "recv error");
    exit(1);
  }
  if('\t' == usrCommand[lineIndex])    {    
    printf("tab comp req\n");
    break;
  }
  lineIndex++;
}
```

I know I am not doing it right, but I dont know what is right method, initially I set the telnet into character mode, later I receive characters from the socket, then I am trying handle whenever tab is pressed.
The problem is I am not able capture tab, I only get \r and \n at the end.

How to capture tab or any method which would answer my question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that lineIndex has been initialized with 0s right?

Comment: Yes Abden, problem is when I press tab it is not sending tab character but it send \r and \n character if I press enter.

Comment: Did you check that the tab character is not interpreted as a series of spaces? Some servers have not implemented the tab character and do this with it.

Comment: No Abend it is not, I checked each index of usrCommand. Am I setting the telnet to character mode correctly? If so why telnet not capturing tab character? Are there any extra settings need to be done? Any masking required?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://pcmicro.com/netfoss/telnet.html You have a couple of setting about horizontal tab. Perhaps some settings are not set properly in your server.